# Dina D’malchuta Dina when it contradicts halachic liability

Tags: halacha, choshen-mishpat-civil-law, beit-din-court, torts-damages, dina-dmalchusa-dina

Does the Halacha of Dina D’malchuta Dina apply to cases where the government law is more lenient than Halacha in liability cases? For example, say someone does something which accidentally leads to property damage and by Halacha they are liable to payment but by secular law they are not liable to payment, can the beit din force them to pay the other party or do they have to defer to secular authorities?

Comment: My guess would be that contractual obligations follow dina dmalchusa because that's the premise of the agreement, but damages follow halacha because the victim didn't waive any rights. I wonder if there are gray areas like car accidents where there's almost a contract dictating who has right of way and who's responsible for damages.

Comment: Let's push your question to extremes.  If some Jews live in a society that condones theft and murder, and some of them engage in same, would halacha let them off the hook?